# How can I declare global variable(CList) in model and/or controller

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I want to declare (and access) global variable(object) of type CList in model and/or controller in yii..

and I want to have two buttons, one for adding new element to the Clist and another for deleting particular element.

So how can i do so???

Comment: Yii is PHP code, so use PHP to do this. But please do tell us more about how your 'global' variable is used, so an appropriate way can be suggested. eg, you can use class constants if your data is of a static nature.

Comment: I want to have an array or Clist, and i'll be adding textfield's data to array or cList, but each time I add data to array or Clist, I think it get's overwritten, because I defined it in that method, and every time I need to call that method to add new value to that array or Clist. So..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, some of which will only be available for a single request, and others across many requests to your application.

If you only require data to be shared between classes and components for a single request, consider using the application params variable.

```
// To store
Yii::app()->params['my_list']= $myvalue;
    ...
// To retrieve
$myvalue = Yii::app()->params['my_list'];
```

If you want the value to remain between separate web page requests, consider using sessions.

```
// To store
Yii::app()->session['my_list']= $myvalue;
    ...
// To retrieve
$myvalue = Yii::app()->session['my_list'];
```

Comment: Good idea, though, but I need an array for storing multiple values from the same textField, and I need six of them for six textfields... So using sessions might not be the right way...

Comment: In that case, use database tables, and store your db reference in sessions.